# Define $t_{n}$ recursively by setting $t_{0} = 0$ and $t_{n} = t_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}(t-t_{n-1})^{2}$. What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}t_{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Suppose that $-1\leq t\leq 1$. Define $t_{n}$ recursively by setting $t_{0} = 0$ and $t_{n} = t_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}(t-t_{n-1})^{2}$. Show that $0\leq t_{n-1}\leq t_{n}\leq |t|$, for all $n\in\textbf{N}$. What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}t_{n}$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

The inequality $t_{n-1} \geq 0$ is obvious, since $t_{0} \geq 0$ and each successive term is obtained from the previous one by adding a non-negative term.

Similarly, one has that $t_{n}\geq t_{n-1}$, because its difference $t_{n} - t_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2}(t-t_{n-1})^{2} \geq 0$.

On the other hand, one has that
\begin{align*}
2(|t| - t_{n}) & = 2|t| - 2t_{n-1} - (t - t_{n-1})^{2}\\\\
& = 2|t| - 2t_{n-1} - |t|^{2} + 2tt_{n-1} - t^{2}_{n-1}\\\\
& = 2 + 2tt_{n-1} - (1-|t|)^{2} - (1+t_{n-1})^{2} = \ldots
\end{align*}

Assuming the relation $t_{n}\leq |t|$ holds, we conclude the sequence $t_{n}$ is increasing and bounded, therefore it converges to the $\sup\{t_{n}\in\textbf{R}\mid n\in\textbf{N}\}$. According to the properties of limits, one has that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} t_{n} & = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(t_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}(t - t_{n-1})^{2}) \Longrightarrow\\\\
L & = L + \frac{1}{2}(t - L)^{2} \Longrightarrow L = t
\end{align*}

Can someone help me finish the proof of $|t| \geq t_{n}$ as well as double-check if I am reasoning right?

Comment: Do you have the problem statement correct? If $t=-1$ then $t_0=0$, $t_1=.5$, $t_2=1.625$ and now we've exceeded $1$.

Comment: I think you are missing the value of $t$ in each recurrence. Indeed, $t_{0} = 0$, $t_{1} = t^{2}/2$ and so on.

Comment: With the problem as stated, any $t<0$ leads to $t_n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For the upper bound you can use induction:

$n=0$ is clear as $t_0 = 0 \leq |t|$.

$n=1$ is also clear since $t_1 = t^2/2 < t^2 <|t|$

Assume that, this inequality holds for $n=k$, that is $t_k < |t|. \quad$ ($1$)

We want to show $t_{k+1} < |t|$. Inspiring by what you did:

$2(|t|-t_{k+1}) = 2|t| - 2t_k -(t-t_k)^2 = 2(|t|-t_k) - (t-t_k)^2 > 2(|t|-t_k) > 0$. So we show

$|t|-t_{k+1} > 0$.

Note that we use $(1)$ in the last two inequality. Hence, by induction, $t_n < |t|$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

And the rest are very good reasoning to get the limit.